# Find the exact value of $\cos\left(\sin^{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{5}\right)\right)$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the exact value of $\cos\left(\sin^{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{5}\right)\right)$.

Another question which I am not able to solve.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: How is this related to optimization?

Comment: Do you know $cos^2 x + sin^2 x = 1$ this identity?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that, by definition
$$y=\arcsin x\iff \sin y =x \enspace\textbf{and}\enspace \color{red}{-\frac\pi2\le y\le\frac\pi2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

Consider a right triangle whose leg is $3$ and hypothenuse is $5$. You still have to deal with the sign.

Answer (score 1):

HINT, use:

$$\cos(\arcsin(x))=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\theta = \sin^{-1}(3/5)$ so that $\theta$ belongs to quadrant I.  If you draw this angle it will form an acute angle of a right triangle with hypotenuse length $5$ and opposite side length $3$.

$\cos(\sin^{-1}(3/5)) = \cos(\theta)$ is the length of the side of this triangle adjacent to angle $\theta$ divided by the length of the hypotenuse.

What is the length of the adjacent side?